# Google Analytics x Clould Flare

Tags: google-analytics, cloudflare

Does someone really understand why Google Analytics and Cloud Flare do not show the same information about Page visitors and users?

I was reading about it but couldn't find a good and reliable answer about it.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CloudFlare tracks traffic instantaneously because any website visitor goes through CloudFlare first to load your page. Google Analytics starts working AFTER your page loads in a browser, if JavaScript is enabled, if staying on the page long enough to give JavaScript a chance to run and send a signal to Google Analytics.

I feel that CloudFlare support answered this question nicely here:
https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200171296-Why-do-my-CloudFlare-traffic-numbers-look-different-than-other-services-Google-Compete-

Comment: Also related, Google Analytics won't count much bot traffic to your site while CloudFlare will track everything. Most bots aren't loading/using JavaScript as mentioned above (although I had one bot do that and make my analytics spike one day).

Comment: Sorry one more note. I generally use CloudFlare to report general activity and threat traffic while using Google Analytics to report user engagement, effectiveness of online ads, etc. I feel they both have a place and the numbers are not expected to match since not all traffic is made up of engaged users.